# Get uncofirmed facebook email address

Tags: android, facebook, email, facebook-graph-api, is-empty

I have a problem with facebook login sdk on Android and iOS.
If the user didn't confirm his email address set on facebook, the API doesn't return his email address with graph api.
How could I get it? Is it possible to get secondary emails?

Facebook login button settings:

```
LoginButton facebookLoginButton = (LoginButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.facebook_login_button);
facebookLoginButton.setReadPermissions("email", "public_profile");
```

This is my callback, with the check "**if (response.getError() != null) {..**" I don't have an error but there is not an email field in the json (me: **{"id":"123456789","name":"Name Surname"}**). This is why the user didn't confirm the email address set on facebook:

```
public static void loginWithFacebook(...) {
    ...

    //permessions check to see if the user removed email permission
    boolean emailOk = loginResult.getAccessToken().getPermissions().contains("email");
    if (emailOk){
        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email");
        GraphRequest req = GraphRequest.newMeRequest( loginResult.getAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(final JSONObject me, final GraphResponse response) {

                        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                boolean emailError = false;
                                String email = "";
                                String errorMessage = "";
                                if (response.getError() != null) {
                                    // there is an error
                                    emailError = true;
                                    errorMessage = "Email address is missing on facebook response";
                                } else {
                                    //It is all ok but the email is empty : {"id":"123456789","name":"Name Surname"}
                                    email = me.optString("email");
                                    String id = me.optString("id");

                                    emailError = TextUtils.isEmpty(email);

                                }


                                if (!emailError){
                                    ...
                                } else {
                                    ...
                                }

                            }
                        });
                        thread.start();



                    }
                });

        req.setParameters(parameters);
        req.executeAsync();

    } else {
        if (socialLoginListener!=null){
            socialLoginListener.onError(TextUtils.getTranslation("facebook_missing_email"));
        }
        ...
    }


}
```

Comment: No, that is not possible. Developers should be able to rely on that an email address they get via API actually belongs to the user.

Comment: facebook email the user already confirmed with the facebook itself.. thats why any social login no need to verify because the provider already verified it